# Session value set in Session_Start not available in Page_PreInit

Tags: asp.net

I am having an intermittent problem with an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application.

In Session_Start, I store the master page file path in the session:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Not shown: get master page path from database

   Session["MasterPagePath"] = PathIGotFromTheDatabase;
}
```

Then in my pages' Page_PreInit, I use that session value to set the Page.MasterPageFile

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MasterPageFile = Session["MasterPagePath"] + @"/MyMasterPage.Master";
}
```

This works 99% of the time, but occasionally something breaks, and Session["MasterPagePath"] is null. The users report that they have to close all of their active browser sessions in order to use the site again.

My understanding is that since I populate the Session["MasterPagePath"] in Session_Start, it should always be available in my pages' PreInit method. If my session had expired, it would always be repopulated by Session_Start before Page_PreInit is called.

Am I missing something here? Under what conditions could what I describe happen? I am using InProc session state for what it's worth.

Comment: I would also assume that   ASP.NET decides in `Page request`-stage(before `Pre_Init`) whether a new Session must be created or not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx
Hence i don't think that this is a "Page-Lifecycle"-Issue.

Comment: What framework are you using? Have you read these comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#10 ?

Comment: @Tim There is an interesting comment there about Session_Start being called twice when two requests come with the same session ID. I was thinking it might be a concurrency or race condition issue along these lines, but my understanding is that ASP.NET is supposed to lock the session where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Session objects added on Application_Start are available at control level. Application["myObj"] would be available but for all users.

More information about the life cycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx).